# How do I use my current credentials with Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, credentials

How do I make [Remote Desktop Connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#Remote_Desktop_Connection) in Windows 7 ([Professional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Main_editions)) use my current domain credentials, instead of prompting me for them, by default. This used to be setup, but when I recreated my [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) domain and reinstalled Windows this feature seemed to stop happening.

For reference, both machines are connected to the same domain. The server I'm trying to connect to is running [Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you start, ensure that your server is configured to allow Single Sign-On (SSO).  If you have a Remote Desktop Session Host, the `Always Prompt for Password` setting should not be set for the connection in `Properties>Log on Settings` and also on the General tab, the Security Layer should be set to Negotiate or SSL.

Also, SSO needs to be enabled on your local / domain policy.  Check the value of `Allow Delegating Default Credentials` here in your GPO:

```
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Credentials Delegation
```

*Also ensure that your server (TERMSRV/) is added to the server list, if required.  You may use wild card characters to add multiple server names*

When you run the Remote Desktop Connection, you should tick the box for `Allow me to save credentials`.
[image]

You will then be prompted to enter your credentials.  When you do so, ensure you tick the box for `Remember my credentials`.  Your credentials should then be saved, and next time you log in it will be passed through.

[image]

Here is a link with some basic step by step instructions: http://itowns.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/enabling-remote-desktop-connection.html

Comment: If you're asked for credentials by Remote Desktop, then you haven't successfully set SSO - even if you "remember" your credentials.  That's kind of the whole point of SSO.  The above screenshots are junk; they SHOULD look like this: http://i.imgur.com/JQbVaFN.png

Answer (score 2):

On the Server do the following steps:

1. click **Start**
2. point to **Administrative Tools**
3. point to **Remote Desktop Services**
4. click **Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration**
5. under **Connections**, right-click the appropriate connection (for example, RDP-Tcp)
6. click **Properties**
7. in the **Properties** dialog box select the **General** tab
8. verify that the **Security Layer** value is set to either **Negotiate** or **SSL (TLS 1.0)**
9. select the **Log on Settings** tab
10. ensure that the **Always prompt for password** check box is not selected
11. click OK.

Comment: This is exactly what I was stating too, but it only addresses the server side, and is specific to RDS, which may or may not be relevant here.

Comment: You still need to set a GPO on the client computers to allow Kerberos delegation; see @RoKa's answer.